# How do add a stand-alone element to the element library in OCC

Tags: oracle, oracle-commerce-cloud

I'm working on a project in Oracle Commerce Cloud (OCC). I'd like to create a new stand-alone element. I've created the directory structure as described in the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E93106_01/Cloud.18A/WidgetDev/html/s0403createtheelementdirectorystructu01.html

but I'm not able to get the new element to appear in the admin's element library when I try to add it to a widget. How can I get my new stand-alone element to appear in the admin's element library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN OCC we cannot se element in admin panel, if you want to make any change and to apply those changes you have to deactivate the whole widget and then reupload it thats how it works